# Lightning Flow for Guest Users on force.com Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, screen-flow

I am trying to run my Lightning Flow on force.com site for guest users using VF page and Lightning app as described below. However, flow is not rendered and throws an error invalid session.

**VFpage:**

```
<apex:page showheader="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <html>
      <head>
         <apex:includeLightning /> 
          <!--Use apex:includeLightning to add the Lightning Components for Visualforce JavaScript library to your Visualforce page-->
      </head>
      <body class="slds-scope">
         <div id="flowContainer" />
         <script>

            var statusChange = function (event) {
               if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
                  var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
                  var key;
                  for(key in outputVariables) {
                     if(outputVariables[key].name === "myOutput") {
                     }
                  }
               }
            };
            $Lightning.use("c:SeatSurvey", function() {
               $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":statusChange},
                  "flowContainer",
                  function (component) {
                     component.startFlow("Partner_Survey", );
                  }
               );
            });
         </script>
         
      </body>
   </html>
   
</apex:page>
```

**Lightning APP:**

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="global" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/>
    
</aura:application>
```

**ERROR:**

```
{"event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:invalidSession","attributes":{"values":{}},"eventDef":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:invalidSession","t":"APPLICATION","xs":"I","a":{"newToken":["newToken","aura://String","I",false]}}},"exceptionMessage":"0DMO10000000tED","exceptionEvent":true}
```

**What Works:**

If I directly embed it in VF page without Lightning APP, it works but Lightning styles are not applied for the flow.

```
<flow:interview name="Partner_Survey" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('/003')}"> 
    </flow:interview>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use a force.com site? You can do the same thing with an Experience Cloud Guest Site User, and avoid many of these issues

Comment: But your code works for me in a dev org with a simple flow, so feel like it must be something else in the org\or something else in the flow?

Comment: Yes, I went with Experience Site with LWC as I need to customize it.